# Where can I find the man page for the set command?

Tags: command-line, gnome

```
$ set frog pets
$ echo $1_$2
frog_pets
```

`man set` is not bringing me anything =( neither is `which set` or `whereis set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set` is a [bash shell command](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

If you type `man bash` and then search for `/abef` should move to the section that describes `set` and the various available.

To confirm that you are using a shell built command you can run:

```
type command
```

if the message `command is a shell builtin` is the output, then you can find the help for these types of commands via

```
help [shell_command]
```

for example:

```
help set
```

As an added bonus you can pipe the output into either `more` or `pager` to enable page-by-page scrolling i.e.

```
help | more
```

or

```
help | pager
```

<sub>(with thanks @psusi & @eljunior & @andrewsomething)</sub>

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: Or try `help set`

Comment: when in doubt, always do `type COMMAND` to see if you are using the command or a shell-builtin function. When it is a builtin,  `help COMMAND | pager` will give you the help with a cool pager. :)